# Disable submit button if checkbox is not checked in jquery

Tags: jquery, forms, checkbox, checked

I have looked on here and tried every answer available, but it is still not working for me. I am trying to disable the submit button if checkbox is not checked. Here is my jquery:

```
var userTerms = $('input#agree');
     if(userTerms.is(':checked')) {
        $("#aggtxt").addClass("err");
        $("#aggtxt").removeClass("error");
        $("#aggtxt").text(" Agreed");
        $("#bookit").attr('disabled', false);
        }else{
        $("#aggtxt").removeClass("err");
        $("#aggtxt").addClass("error");
        $("#aggtxt").text(" Please check terms and conditions box");
        $("#bookit").attr('disabled', true);
        }

         if ($('#bookit').is(':disabled') == true) { 
            $("#booktxt").removeClass("err");
            $("#booktxt").addClass("error");
            $("#booktxt").text(" Before you can submit this form please check the errors in form marked in red.");
            }else{
                $("#booktxt").addClass("err");
                $("#booktxt").removeClass("error");
                $("#booktxt").text(" Your information looks good, continue to booking...");
                }   
});
```

and part of my HTML form:

```
<p><span id="aggtxt"></span><br /><input type="checkbox" name="agree" id="agree" />  I agree to <a href="http://travel.ian.com/index.jsp?pageName=userAgreement&locale=en_US&cid=379849" target="_blank">Terms and Conditions</a> and understand Cancellation Policy.<p>
<span id="booktxt"></span>
<input type="submit" name="bookit" value="" class="bookit" id="bookit" />
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

My take on this:

http://jsfiddle.net/bluz/peans/

Hope this helps :)
Paz.

Comment: u havent used "Var" to declare a variable in ur script
this is the correct one
http://jsfiddle.net/peans/39/

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
$("#bookit").attr('disabled', 'disabled');
```

I tried this:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="agree" id="agree" onclick="$('#bookit').attr('disabled', !$(this).is(':checked'));" />
    I agree to <a href="http://travel.ian.com/index.jsp?pageName=userAgreement&locale=en_US&cid=379849" target="_blank">Terms and Conditions</a> and understand Cancellation Policy.<p>
```

And it disables the button if you uncheck the checkbox.

Comment: New hotness!! `$el.prop('disabled', true)`

Comment: the disabled button code works fine, cause I also have it with other parts of the form.. it is only failing when I check if check box is checked.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
if($('#agree').val() == 'true')
```

More info on jQuery [documentation](http://api.jquery.com/checked-selector/).

**Correction**:

`is(':checked')` method only return when a radio/check box is checked.

Comment: @liveandream I corrected it now, you should test whether the checkbox is checked or not .